# I want to take value from one API response body and use into another api request using Cucumber gherkin

Tags: java, performance-testing, bdd, rest-assured, cucumber-java

Scenario: Verify the manifest of published app
1. Given Base url "baseUrl" and path "basepath"
2. And Headers are
3. And Query parameter
4. And App with below details
5. When I execute the another API with Base url "baseUrl" and path "basePath"
6. And Append with Attributevalue (complete url will be , baseUrl + basePath + AttributeValue )
7. And api headers
8. And query parameters
9. Then Success message with 200 status code

Comment: What is the question? What did you try? Please provide your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have implemented something very similar recently. You can utilize below code and modify it to your need. You'll probably need to omit some steps from your feature . Those steps are included as part of step def implementation in below code

Feature

```
@get
  Scenario: get employee
    
    Given an employee exist in the database with id "2"
   When  user retrieves employee info by id
    Then the status code for get employee is 200
```

StepDefs

```
import io.cucumber.java.en.Given;
import io.cucumber.java.en.When;
import io.cucumber.java.en.Then;
import io.cucumber.java.en.And;


import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath;


import io.restassured.response.Response;
import io.restassured.response.ValidatableResponse;
import io.restassured.specification.RequestSpecification;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;
    public class secondIT {
        
        public static Response response;
        public static ValidatableResponse json;
        public static RequestSpecification request;
        public  static String id;
         public static JsonPath jsonPathEvaluator;
        
        
      
        @Given("an employee exist in the database with id {string}")
        public void an_employee_exists_with_id(String ID){
            secondIT.id=ID;
            RestAssured.baseURI = "http://dummy.www.com/api/v1";
            secondIT.request = RestAssured.given();
        }
        
        @When("user retrieves employee info by id")
        public void user_retrieves_employee_info_by_id(){
            
            secondIT.response = secondIT.request.pathParam("id", secondIT.id).get("/employee/{id}");
            secondIT.jsonPathEvaluator = secondIT.response.jsonPath();
            assertNotNull(response);
            
        }
        
        @Then("the status code for get employee is {int}")
        public void verify_status(int sc){
            System.out.println("status code check..  " );
            secondIT.json = secondIT.response.then().statusCode(sc);
            System.out.println("status code:  " + secondIT.response.getStatusCode());
            assertEquals(sc,secondIT.response.getStatusCode());
        }
}
```